# If Service Worker requires html to be in same folder as servive_worker.js, how can I use EJS (which requires Views folder)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, ejs, http-caching

I have a really simple web app to practice making Service Workers on. The issue that i'm having is that i'm using EJS, and EJS requires that the html is kept in a Views folder. To cache the HTML I have to have the service worker JS file in the same location as the HTML - but it fails if I do this! I get an error stating that the HTML must be in the EJS views file

If I move the HTML into Views, then I don't get an error, but the Service Worker doesn't cache anything!

Please can someone advise me?

Here is my current folder structure, where the service worker doesn't error out - but then doesn't cache anything either:

[image]

Where would I out my EJS file so it caches? It apparently requires its own folder to house the HTML

Here is my server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const request = require('request');
const apiKey = '<api key>';

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('weather_html');
})

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  let city = req.body.city;
  let url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid=${apiKey}`
request(url, function (err, response, body) {
    if(err){
      res.render('weather_html', {weather: null, error: 'Error, please try again'});
    } else {
      let weather = JSON.parse(body)
      if(weather.main == undefined){
        res.render('weather_html', {weather: null, error: 'Error, please try again'});
      } else {
        let weatherText = `It's ${weather.main.temp} degrees in ${weather.name}!`;
        res.render('weather_html', {weather: weatherText, error: null});
      }
    }
  });
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('server is listening on port 3000!')
});
```

Here is the bastard service_worker.js file:

```
const filesToCache = [
  '/'
];

const staticCacheName = 'this is the SW\'s cache';

self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  console.log('Attempting to install service worker and cache whatever is in filesToCache');
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(staticCacheName)
    .then(cache => {
      return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  console.log('Fetch event for ', event.request.url);
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
    .then(response => {
      if (response) {
        console.log('Found ', event.request.url, ' in cache');
        return response;
      }
      console.log('Network request for ', event.request.url);
      return fetch(event.request)

      .then(response => {

  return caches.open(staticCacheName).then(cache => {
    cache.put(event.request.url, response.clone());
    return response;
  });
});

    }).catch(error => {

    })
  );
});
```

My EJS/HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test weather app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Test weather search app</p>
    <img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/AECE/production/_99805744_gettyimages-625757214.jpg">
    <div class="container">
      <fieldset>
        <form action="/" method="post">
          <input name="city" type="text" class="ghost-input" placeholder="Enter a City" required>
          <input type="submit" class="ghost-button" value="Enter a city name for temperature in celsius">
        </form>
        <% if(locals.weather !== null){ %>
          <p><%= locals.weather %></p>
        <% } %>

        <% if(locals.error !== null){ %>
          <p><%= locals.error %></p>
        <% } %>
    </fieldset>
    </div>
  <!-- Service Worker - Checks if the browser supports a service worker, if so, registers the file server_worker.js as the SW, then logs to console-->
  <script>
  if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker
             .register('/service_worker.js')
             .then(function() { console.log("Service Worker Registered"); });
  }
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a screenshot of the SW without errors, using the current folder structure. I want it to be able to cache the HTML in the views folder:

[image]

Comment: "To cache the HTML I have to have the service worker JS file in the same location as the HTML" — It doesn't. Even if it did, the location that matters is based on the **URLs** and not on the filesystem structure on your server.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was reading this - https://gist.github.com/Rich-Harris/fd6c3c73e6e707e312d7c5d7d0f3b2f9 and it seems to align with what people are saying? I'm new to all of this. I believe that the URL behaviour is set in the server through GET methods if you visit a URL. so '/' serves my page

Answer (score 0):

You can change the structure of the folders to be like so:

[image]

Then in the server.js file you make such thatyou reference your static files (and actually place them!) in the public folder:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

One other note, I found that if anything is called and returns a 404 response, then the SWW cannot be registered and installed